# What is the escape key in PuTTY

Tags: putty

I want to see what tunnel is used in my connection I'm  using PuTTY so I want to know the escape key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The special command sequences available are described in the "[Using PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html)" documentation page.

However, to check the tunnels you have open, you would right-click the PuTTY icon in the upper-left corner of the window and choose "Change Settings", then drill down to Connection → SSH → Tunnels.  From here you and view and modify the tunnels you're using.

Answer (score 1):

With Putty, if you want to send an escape char (like ^[ with telnet), just press CTRL and $.
Also, it may depends of your keyboard layout, as explain of the following link [Putty escape chars](http://blog.frosty-geek.net/2010/11/putty-and-better-known-as-escape.html).